# web3.py - How does web3.auto choose a provider node?

Tags: parity, web3.py, web3-providers

I'm having **[this other issue](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/58091/eth-gettransactionreceipt-returns-null-only-sometimes-and-only-on-my-node-tx-is)** which has forced me to rely on either Infura or `web3.auto` in order to call `getTransactionReceipt`.  I've noticed that when I create a w3 instance from `web3.auto` it almost always successfully returns a receipt when I call `getTransactionReceipt`. This leads me to wonder how `web3.auto` chooses a provider node:

1. Does it only select full nodes?
2. Does it ever select parity pruning nodes or light nodes?
3. Are there any other restrictions?

I'm curious for 1, and for 2 I'd like to use this answer to apply it to my above-linked issue to see if I can determine why my parity node always returns `None` when I call `getTransactionReceipt`.

Answer (score 1):

From the [docs](https://web3py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/providers.html#how-automated-detection-works):

> ### How Automated Detection Works
>
> Web3 attempts to connect to nodes in the following order, using the first succesful connection it can make:
>
> - The connection specified by an environment variable, see [Provider via Environment Variable](https://web3py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/providers.html#provider-uri)
> - [IPCProvider](https://web3py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/providers.html#web3.providers.ipc.IPCProvider), which looks for several IPC file locations
> - [HTTPProvider](https://web3py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/providers.html#web3.providers.rpc.HTTPProvider), which attempts to connect to “http://localhost:8545”

The docs are getting a bit stale, but should be a good place to start. I just noticed it is missing the `WebsocketProvider`, which is attempted after `HTTPProvider`. In the end, the best documentation is the code. For example, [`IPCProvider`'s default location is set using](https://github.com/ethereum/web3.py/blob/master/web3/providers/ipc.py#L67):

```
def get_default_ipc_path(testnet=False):
    if testnet:
        testnet = "testnet"
    else:
        testnet = ""

    if sys.platform == 'darwin':
        ipc_path = os.path.expanduser(os.path.join(
            "~",
            "Library",
            "Ethereum",
            testnet,
            "geth.ipc"
        ))
        if os.path.exists(ipc_path):
            return ipc_path

        ipc_path = os.path.expanduser(os.path.join(
            "~",
            "Library",
            "Application Support",
            "io.parity.ethereum",
            "jsonrpc.ipc"
        ))
        if os.path.exists(ipc_path):
            return ipc_path

    elif sys.platform.startswith('linux') or sys.platform.startswith('freebsd'):
        ipc_path = os.path.expanduser(os.path.join(
            "~",
            ".ethereum",
            testnet,
            "geth.ipc"
        ))
        if os.path.exists(ipc_path):
            return ipc_path

        ipc_path = os.path.expanduser(os.path.join(
            "~",
            ".local",
            "share",
            "io.parity.ethereum",
            "jsonrpc.ipc"
        ))
        if os.path.exists(ipc_path):
            return ipc_path

    elif sys.platform == 'win32':
        ipc_path = os.path.join(
            "\\\\",
            ".",
            "pipe",
            "geth.ipc"
        )
        if os.path.exists(ipc_path):
            return ipc_path

        ipc_path = os.path.join(
            "\\\\",
            ".",
            "pipe",
            "jsonrpc.ipc"
        )
        if os.path.exists(ipc_path):
            return ipc_path
```